# Place data in multiple cells with command button

Tags: excel, vba

I connected two weighing scales to my PC and used a VBA tutorial and the XMComm to create Excel userform that collects the weight data from a scale and places it in a cell.

I can retrieve the weight from each scale with separate command buttons. I would like to combine both scales into one command button.

I've tried by putting `ActiveCell.Offset(0,1).Select` between the two Userforms in the command button. However, when I use this command button, the Active Cell shifts right immediately and only one of the two weight values is placed.

I use `ActiveCell` to place this information in any cells.

I think it may be an issue with the individual userforms themselves. When I try to place a single weight from a command button tied to just one userform, the weight is sometimes not placed.

Here is the userform code:

```
Private Sub XMCommCRC1_OnComm()
    Static sInput As String
    Dim sTerminator As String
    Dim Buffer As Variant

' Branch according to the CommEvent property
    Select Case XMCommCRC1.CommEvent
    Case XMCOMM_EV_RECEIVE
        Buffer = XMCommCRC1.InputData ' Use Input property for MSComm
        sInput = sInput & Buffer
        If Worksheets("Settings").Range("Terminator") = "CR/LF" Then
            sTerminator = vbCrLf
        Else
            sTerminaotr = vbCr
        End If
        If Right$(sInput, Len(sTerminator)) = sTerminator Then
            XMCommCRC1.PortOpen = False
            sInput = Left$(sInput, Len(sInput) - Len(sTerminator))
            Select Case Left$(sInput, 2)
            Case "ST", "S "
                ActiveCell.Value = CDbl(Mid$(sInput, 7, 8))
                ActiveCell.Activate
            Case "US", "SD"
                MsgBox "The balance is unstable."
            Case "OL", "SI"
                MsgBox "The balance is showing an eror value."
            End Select
            sInput = ""
        End If
    End Select
End Sub


Public Sub RequestBalanceData()
    With Worksheets("Settings")
' Configure and open the COM port
        If Not XMCommCRC1.PortOpen Then
            XMCommCRC1.RThreshold = 1
            XMCommCRC1.RTSEnable = True
            XMCommCRC1.CommPort = .Range("COM_Port")
            XMCommCRC1.Settings = .Range("Baud_Rate") & "," & _
            .Range("Parity") & "," & _
            .Range("Data_Bits") & "," & _
            .Range("Stop_Bits")
            XMCommCRC1.PortOpen = True
        End If

' Send balance's "SI" (Send Immediate) command
' to request weighing data immediately
        If .Range("Terminator") = "CR/LF" Then
            XMCommCRC1.Output = "R" & vbCrLf
        Else
            XMCommCRC1.Output = "R" & vbCr
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

I am using Excel 2007.
The VBA tutorial - http://www.msclims.com/lims/diybalance.html
The link to XMCOMM - http://www.hardandsoftware.net/xmcomm.htm

Comment: Instead of relying on `ActiveCell`, use a fully qualified reference to the cell you want to update.

Comment: I'd need to be able to do this a lot in this file, so I need it to be able to place this information in any cells.